# Is consecutive observations only is a prerequisite of fixed effect estimation in panel data?

Tags: regression, panel-data, fixed-effects-model

As is in the title, I'm curious: Is including only the consecutive observations of an ID in longitudinal data a prerequisite for estimating ID level fixed effect?

For instance, I have longitudinal data with the structure of firm_id-year. There is one value of firm_id, say, 'Corp_Umbrella,' with the value of `sales` at years 1998, 1999, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2010, 1011, 2012.

To run an estimation with firm fixed-effect, do I need to keep only consecutive observations of 'Corp_Umbrella', i.e., only observations from 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005 (the maximum consecutive groups)? Or I can have all of the observations as long as there is more than 1 observation in each 'firm_id'?